# How to get rid of New Tab and Split View buttons in zsh konsole?

Tags: linux, zsh

Recently I have installed linux to explore its customization. Now I'm trying to configure zsh konsole and I would like to get rid of all buttons at top because I don't use them. I managed to get rid of menu bar but I can't remove bar with "New Tab" button.

[my konsole with bar I'm trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1euc.png)

Is there a setting I can add to `~/.config/konsolerc`?

Comment: Hi, this site is for specific programming questions. Maybe your question fits better on [Unix & LInux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What exactly is "**zsh** konsole"? the file `konsolerc` is usually associated with the KDE program `Konsole`?

Comment: Yeah, I've figured it out. Sorry for the misunderstanding it is KDE Konsole and I got rid of it by unchecking Settings > Toolbars to show > *all options*